# Not able to POST http://localhost:5000/api/createuser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, bootstrap-5

While pursuing a MERN stack project tutorial on YouTube, I've encountered an obstacle in the midst of my progress. The specific issue revolves around the implementation of user registration, a recent addition to my project. I've been using ThunderClient to test this feature, and it seems to be causing a challenge. To address this problem effectively, I would appreciate guidance and assistance, particularly in the form of error messages or code snippets related to the registration process.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k2Ej.png)

the result should have been success But I am getting error please help! :)

this is the main index file
Index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 5000
const mongoDB = require("./db")

app.get('/', (req, res) =\> {
res.send('Hello World!')
})
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', require("./Routes/CreateUser"));
app.listen(port, () =\> {
console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}) })
```

this is the db file
db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoURI = 'mongodb+srv://Nikita:shani@cluster0.e8wdets.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
const mongoDB =async()=>{
   await mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true }, async (err, result) => {
        if (err) console.log("---", err);
        else {
            console.log("connected");
            const fetched_data = await mongoose.connection.db.collection("food_items");
            fetched_data.find({}).toArray(function (err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                else console.log(data);

            });

        }

    });
}

module.exports = mongoDB;
```

this is the user file
User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    location:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    },

  });

  module.exports = mongoose.model('user',UserSchema)
```

this is the sample file to check whether the data is being stored in the database or not
CreateUser.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const User = require('../models/User')

router.post("/creatuser", async (req, res)=>{
    try {
        await User.create({
            name: "Shyam Das",
            password: "123456",
            email: "shyamdas12@hotmail.com", 
            location: "Qwerty edrfef"
        })
    res.json({success:true});    

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.json({success:false});
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `CreateUser.js` file there is a typo error:

```
router.post("/creatuser", async (req, res)=>{...} // You wrote "creatuser"
router.post("/createuser", async (req, res)=>{...} // Change it to "createuser"
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I have made the changes still it I am getting the same error. One thing I would like to add in the db.js folder in the 9th line the toArray is being slashed by the vscode and its showing (The signature '(callback: Callback<WithId<Document>[]>): void' of 'fetched_data1.toArray' is deprecated.ts(6387)
mongodb.d.ts(116, 9): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.) What should i do sir?

Comment: The 404 error was caused by the typo I described in my answer. The error you are getting now is different and I suggest you to ask it in a new thread, providing the mongoose version you are using. Moreover, I can tell you the way you are triyng to connect mongo is strange. You are defining a connect function without never calling it. Also I don't understand why your connect function should retrieve data from the database. Finally, I would not share in public the credentials to access your mongodb istance, even if it's a test/dev istance.

Comment: okay sir noted. I just followed the  steps from youtube video also this is my first time asking question on StackOverFlow I will make sure to not share any credentials next time onwards . I have got the error fixed , I  just degraded the mongoose version and the problem was fixed. Thank you so much for helping :-)